# How to send an email to 2 recipients & both recipients see each other in the to field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer, mandrill

**How can I send an email to 2 people and have them both see each other in the to field of the email?**

Below is my code, which does send emails to both people, but both email recipients don't see each other. I am using Mandrill to send out my emails (don't know if this information helps).

**User_mailer.rb (File in app/mailers)**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
default from: 'Mauricio@example.com'

def email(user)
   mail(to: "1@gmail.com, 2@gmail.com",
   subject: 'Send email to 2 email accounts', 
   body: 'Email to be sent to 2 email accounts. Both recipients should see each other.')
end
```

**Routes.rb (File in Config)**

```
get 'sendemail' => 'users#send_email'
```

**new.html.erb (File in app/views/users)**

```
<%= link_to "Send email to both emails", sendemail_path %>
```

**users_controller.rb (File in app/controllers)**

```
def send_email
   UserMailer.email(@user).deliver
   redirect_to users_path
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you're sending the `X-MC-PreserveRecipients` header and it's set to `true`.

```
If you send to more than one recipient at a time and want all recipients to
see each other recipient's information, use the X-MC-PreserveRecipients 
header. Recipients will be able to reply-all and see other recipient
information if this is set to true. If it's set to false, Mandrill will 
rewrite the To and Cc headers for your email and only show information 
about an individual recipient.
```

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582117-Using-SMTP-Headers-to-customize-your-messages#preserve-recipient-headers-for-group-emails

Comment: Thank you! I set the X-MC-PreserveRecipients to true and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Mandrill's [Message API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.ruby.html) allows for this---set `preserve_recipients` to `true`.

Comment: Thank you! The Mandrill API was helpful as I learned that there are so many features that I can incorporate into my emails. I set preserve recipients to true and it worked.